# Long string model of black hole

Tags: string-theory, black-holes

I wonder if anyone can advise me  literature about "long string model" of black hole. I've tried [Google](http://www.google.com/search?as_q=%22black+hole%22&as_epq=long+string), and of course [arXiv.org](http://search.arxiv.org:8081/?query=%22black+hole%22+%22long+string%22&in=). Still I couldn't find anything about this theme. I would be also very pleased if someone could tell me any information about calculation of correlation functions of massive scalar field living on the circle.

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about the same thing, the long string picture of a black hole which was originally referred to as a "long brane", it was introduced in the paper by Susskind and Maldacena in 1996

> http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9604042

See also its 200+ followups.